# performing pause of activity that is not resumed after recreate method

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

I have a project for HoneyComb and I get an error after use recreate() method at onResum() method in my main Activity.

```
11-10 22:05:42.090: E/ActivityThread(1917): Performing pause of activity that is not     resumed: {com.blogspot.honeyapp/com.blogspot.honeyapp.Main}
11-10 22:05:42.090: E/ActivityThread(1917): java.lang.RuntimeException: Performing pause of activity that is not resumed: {com.blogspot.honeyapp/com.blogspot.honeyapp.Main}
11-10 22:05:42.090: E/ActivityThread(1917):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2517)
11-10 22:05:42.090: E/ActivityThread(1917):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2505)
11-10 22:05:42.090: E/ActivityThread(1917):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handlePauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2483)
11-10 22:05:42.090: E/ActivityThread(1917):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:122)
11-10 22:05:42.090: E/ActivityThread(1917):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1031)
11-10 22:05:42.090: E/ActivityThread(1917):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-10 22:05:42.090: E/ActivityThread(1917):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
11-10 22:05:42.090: E/ActivityThread(1917):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4123)
11-10 22:05:42.090: E/ActivityThread(1917):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-10 22:05:42.090: E/ActivityThread(1917):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
11-10 22:05:42.090: E/ActivityThread(1917):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
11-10 22:05:42.090: E/ActivityThread(1917):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
11-10 22:05:42.090: E/ActivityThread(1917):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I create a new project to show you what's happen.

You can find it at http://xp-dev.com/svn/RecreateError/trunk/

I don't know what's my fault but I start Activity and log the Activity's lifecycle.
The result:

```
11-10 22:26:45.960: I/seasons log(2274): onCreate()
11-10 22:26:45.990: I/seasons log(2274): onStart()
11-10 22:26:45.990: I/seasons log(2274): onResume()
```

Now I press the Action Bar Icon to activate the recreate flag and change to other app...

```
11-10 22:30:26.390: I/seasons log(2274): onPause()
11-10 22:30:27.080: I/seasons log(2274): onStop()
```

And return to my Activity with recreate flag activated what will done recreate() at onResume().

```
11-10 22:33:05.500: I/seasons log(2274): onCreate()
11-10 22:33:05.510: I/seasons log(2274): onStart()
11-10 22:33:05.510: I/seasons log(2274): onResume()
11-10 22:33:05.510: I/seasons log(2274): onPause()
```

onPause? But my Activity is visible, what I'm doing wrong? The correct status aren't onResume()?

And now if I change to another app I get the error.

Thanks for your time and sorry for my bad English.

---

At this time I don't understand how applications like File Manager HD do this action.

Two Activities: Main Activity A, Activity B with PreferenceFragment as main content.

One option that changes theme between Holo and Holo.Light,
Activity B changes with a `OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener` method in PreferenceFragment but when we come back to the Main Activity `recreate()` method at `onResume()` fails, how to do This?

I'm confussed. Sorry.

Answer (score 3):

To do this, use a handler:

```
Handler handler = new Handler() {
       @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
           if(msg.what==MSG_RECREATE)
               recreate();
        }
};

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    if(condition) {
        Message msg = handler.obtainMessage();
        msg.what = MSG_RECREATE;
        handler.sendMessage(msg);
    }
}
```

This will not crash anymore.

Comment: I believe it will still crash, if you don't call `super.onResume()` :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the cause for your problems but you don't compare Strings like this in Java;

```
protected void onResume() {
    ...
    if (recreate == "S") {
        recreate = "N";
        recreate();
    }
```

Use `if ("S".equals(recreate))` instead.

Comment: Ups. In the real app this code don't exist but thank you. A great mistake for me.

Answer (score 0):

You should never be calling `onPause onCreate onResume` etc on your own. You shouldn't need to use `recreate()` for what you want to do, put initialisation code elsewhere if it needs updating. Further, use an integer to store the state of the program instead of a string, then declare some final variables to reference e.g.

```
public final int RECREATE_ON = 1;
public final int RECREATE_OFF = 2;
private int recreate = RECREATE_OFF;

...

if(recreate==RECREATE_ON){
    recreate();
}
```

Remember what recreate() is doing:

> Cause this Activity to be recreated with a new instance. This results
>   in essentially the same flow as when the Activity is created due to a
>   configuration change -- the current **instance will go through its
>   lifecycle to onDestroy()** and a new instance then created after it.

This is why you are getting the `onPause` message.

Comment: I don't call onPause, onCreate, onResume on my own. But yoy are right with recreate. I use this in my app because on a PreferenceFragment I change the theme between holo and Holo.light and I need to recreate the activity when come back to see changes.

Comment: I think you shouldn't decide what other people do need. If you don't know a solution, just don't answer.