# The recreate() method causes an activity to be automatically (recreated and) paused on emulator api level 16...24

Tags: android, onpause, recreate

Suppose you have two activities: **A** (launcher) and **B**. Activity **A** has a button, when you press it, activity **B** is started for result. When the user presses the back key, in the method `onActivityResult()` of activity **A**, put a call to the method `recreate()`. What happens is that the activity **A** is recreated, resumed and *automatically* paused (that is, the `onPause()` method is called after `onResume()`, but the activity is fully visible, of course). This happens on the emulator, api level 16,17,18,19,21,22,23. This does not happen on a real api 23 smartphone. You can put a flag inside `onActivityResult()` and call the `recreate()` method from `onResume()` and get the same result. Is this a bug of android emulators or am i missing something?
A part of the gradle file:

```
  compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.test.test2"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
```

### Update

I see that someone else found the same strange behaviour: [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8086697/performing-pause-of-activity-that-is-not-resumed-after-recreate-method?rq=1). I think i have added some more info.

Comment: I would investigate your instance control in the manifest. You may be having a single instance allowed where the old one is alive until you relaunch a new version of it, in which case it starts the new one ending the old one. There are a few odd behaviors that can happen depending on how you launch the intent, and your manifest configuration of the activity. Not to say it's not a bug, but often times the Google specific emulators and Google specific phones are more strict on these things where other OEMs may just handle it.

Comment: @Sam Both activities are singleTop, the intent has no special flags. It is a project started from scratch, just to test this behaviour.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on this statement "put a call to the method recreate(). What happens is that the activity A is recreated," I'm not sure what you mean by "put a call to the method recreate(). Are you saying that the onCreate is automatically called? or are you implying something else like you call your own recreate routine?

Comment: @Sam In A.onActivityResult() (when we return from B to A), call the recreate() method. Or, set some flag to true and call recreate() method from A.onResume(). The recreate() method is a method of the Activity class (of the sdk, not mine). What happens is that the activity A is recreated and resumed, and that is obviously ok, but it is also automatically put in a paused state (the onPause() method is automatically called).